# Jquery select td value from inside another td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

i've looked in the manual to search for the next value in a table but the problem is that i'm in the first span cell 'cause of the event catch by :

jQuery code:

```
$('span[name="checkSeleccion"]').live('click',function(){       
    alert($(this).attr('id')+"::"+$(this).next('td').html());
});
```

HTML code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <span id="606" class="checkboxClear" rel="606-null-335" name="checkSeleccion">&nbsp;</span>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top:6px;">http://www.hithere.com</td>
    <td align="center" style="padding-top:6px;">335</td>
    </tr>
</tobdy>
```

is there a way to catch the second td value when the span is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `.parent()`:

```
$('span[name="checkSeleccion"]').live('click', function() {       
  alert(this.id + "::" + $(this).parent().next('td').html());
});
```

Also note that `$(this).attr('id')` could be written as just `this.id`, which is much more efficient (and easier to type!).

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$(this).next('td')
```

to this:

```
$(this).parent('td').next('td')
```

Answer (score 1):

add the **.parent()** selector:

```
alert($(this).attr('id')+"::"+$(this).parent().next('td').html()); });
```

Comment: `.parent()` is not a selector.